# Receive user Messages via `node-telegram-bot-api` module

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Why This Code Get User Messages in any Places or I mean in any Buttons.

With this code, I will receive user messages, and I excluded `buttons` and `previous buttons` Because I need Just console log Users real messages(not Buttons Title),
I need to get user Messages just when I'm in `Contact us` Button.

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (!locale.keyboards[msg.text] &&
    !msg.text.includes("Previous Buttons ")) {
    console.log("User Message is: " + msg.text)
    const opts = {
      reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        keyboard: arrangeKeyboardWithOut(locale.keyboards["/start"].childs, 2, msg),
        resize_keyboard: true,
        one_time_keyboard: true
      })
    };
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Received your message', opts);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I Maked These Two Function

```
var getmessage = async () => {
  // Listen for any kind of message. There are different kinds of messages.
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bot.on('message', (msg) => {
      if (!locale.keyboards[msg.text] &&
        !msg.text.includes("previous button")) {
        console.log("user message is: " + msg.text)
        const opts = {
          reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
          reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            keyboard: arrangeKeyboardWithOut(locale.keyboards["/start"].childs, 2, msg),
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true
          })
        };
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, ' your message recieved', opts);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
  return
}

var getmessage1 = async () => {
  await getmessage();
}
```

Then I called in my `else if`

```
else if (msg.text == ["contact us"]) {
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: arrangeKeyboard(locale.keyboards[msg.text].childs, 2, msg),
          resize_keyboard: true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Please Write your Messages:", opts);
      getmessage1();
    }
```